# Why is my connection not able to open? MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, dsn

In Access 2013 VBA I am trying to open the connection:

```
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        connectionString = "ODBC;DSN=MyDSN;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;DATABASE=MyTest"
        cn.Open (connectionString)
```

I have validated and used "MyDSN" in other code so I know that the DSN settings are correct. When I execute the code above I get a run-time 80004005 error telling me that the "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Can I use a DSN connection with an ADODB connection?

Comment: Since the VBA is in Access, are you trying to connect to the same database? If so, you can just do: Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discard *"ODBC;"* from the connection string.  (I think supplying a DSN value already establishes that you want an ODBC connection.)

This example fails at `cn.Open` on my system with the same error message you reported ...

```vb
ConnectionString = "ODBC;DSN=sqlserver_local;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=testbed"
```

But discarding *"ODBC;"* allowed `cn.Open` to succeed ...

```vb
ConnectionString = "DSN=sqlserver_local;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=testbed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following connection string (sample only) which is working fine with Access 2003 and 2013 versions:

```
DRIVER= {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ= C:\Test.mdb; DefaultDir = C:\; UID= admin; PWD= admin; FIL = MS Access; MaxBufferSize = 2048; MaxScanRows = 8; PageTimeout = 5; SafeTransactions = 0; Threads = 4; UserCommitSync = Yes;
```